# How can I get what I'm looking for here?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date

I think this question has been answered but I am not skilled enough (yet!) to have recognized how someone elses' answer will help me fix my problem so I apologize if this feels like a repost.

I am using MS Server2012

I need the following results from a query:

> LoanNumber | OpenDate | CreditLimit | CaptureDate | CaptureBalance | TodayDate | TodayBalance

LoanNumber is a unique identifier | OpenDate is the date the credit line was opened | CaptureDate is OpenDate + 6 days | CaptureBalance is what we consider to be the initial balance on the credit line and is defined as the balance 6 days after it was opened | TodayDate is today | TodayBalance is the balance today

I want to be able to look at a credit line and compare the initial balance (aka CaptureBalance) to the credit limit as well as compare that to the balance today.

Here's my code and see below for more definitions

```
select top 100
 L1.LOANNUMBER      as 'LoanNumber'
,L1.OPENDATE        as 'OpenDate' --this is stored as Date
,L2.OPENDATE+6      as 'CaptureDate'
,L1.CREDITLIMIT     as 'CreditLimit'
,(  Select L2.BALANCE
    From LOAN as L2
    INNER JOIN LOAN as L1 on L2.LOANNUMBER = L1.LOANNUMBER
    Where CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),L2.RUNDATE )) = L2.OPENDATE+6
    ) as 'CaptureBalance'

From LOAN as L1
INNER JOIN LOAN as L2 on L1.LOANNUMBER = L2.LOANNUMBER

Where L1.RUNDATE = 20151130  -- this is stored as INT
and L1.[TYPE] = 'Line of Credit'
```

RUNDATE is important because every day our system logs a snapsot of that loan. `Where L1.RUNDATE = 20151130` is telling the system to give me the balance on Nov 30 2015. I also need to get what the balance was 6 days after the date the loan was opened causing me to reference 2 different run dates.

I have to compare the run date (INT) to OpenDate (Date) so I used `CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),L2.RUNDATE ))` to convert the run date INT --> Date so I can effectively compare the two dates.

When I run this I get:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Initially I was running all of this off of the same table. Then I decided to try giving the loan table 2 different aliases and that's where I stopped.

Is the way I'm using that subquery resulting in "more than 1 value" because each result of that query is trying to get listed as a column header? If yes, I still don't know how to get what I'm looking for.

HELP!?

Comment: I don't understand this query at all. Your subquery can return more than 1 row so you are seeing the error. You also should get in the habit of using DATEADD instead of just adding 6 to a datetime value. Perhaps this would be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: First of all, avoid re-using table aliases in a query.   You use L1 & L2 in both your main query and your sub-query.  Don't do that.   Second of all, I think you either don't need the self-join, or you don't need the sub-query;  they seem to be redundant attempts to achieve the same goal.

Comment: There are a couple different approaches but first, I need clarification.  How many records are you dealing with for a given run date?  Also, can a loan have multiple records in the loan table for a single day?  I am assuming yes on the second question because of your error.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some sample records?  Perhaps in the form of a INSERT statement, so other can reproduce the data?

Comment: Just noticed this, is this intentional in your WHERE clause Where CONVERT(datetime,convert(char(8),L2.RUNDATE )) = L2.OPENDATE+6.  I would think your L2.RUNDATE should be L1.RUNDATE.  Reason, L1 in your subquery has nothing to filter it down to one record, producing multiple causing the error.

Comment: Come on you can come up with a better title than "How can get what I am looking for here?"

Comment: @Frisbee - It got _your_ attention. ;-) And, I am kind of proud to know I've grown my skills to the point that I was able to provide enough context and information to have been able to get the answer I needed on the first try! Baby steps!

Comment: Oh, so that is the best you can do.   Got my attention in a bad way.  I read nothing and would never have attempt to answer.

Comment: I think your underwear must be on backwards @Frisbee. Lighten up.

Comment: Brand new user with two down votes and now name calling.  Grow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is what you want, or at least one approach to it:

```
select top 100
 L1.LOANNUMBER      as 'LoanNumber'
,L1.OPENDATE        as 'OpenDate' --this is stored as Date
,L2.RUNDATE      as 'CaptureDate'
,L1.CREDITLIMIT     as 'CreditLimit'
,L2.BALANCE as 'CaptureBalance'
,L1.RUNDATE as 'TodayDate'
,L1.BALANCE as 'TodayBalance'

From LOAN as L1
INNER JOIN LOAN as L2 
  on L1.LOANNUMBER = L2.LOANNUMBER
  AND L2.RUNDATE=DATEADD(dd, 6, L1.OPENDATE)

Where L1.RUNDATE = 20151130  -- this is stored as INT
and L1.[TYPE] = 'Line of Credit'
```

Comment: Definitely a better alternative for a correlated sub query that is evaluated for every record.  This is a good suggestion @bteague

Comment: Thank you for this - but now I'm getting "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type smalldatetime" EDIT: I converted rundate to a date format and now it works perfectly! Thank you @Tab